# $nextTick directly from a Javascript script

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm wondering if there's a way of use the $nextTick AlpineJS magic property in a javascript script (the "$nextTick" is not recognize):

```
<div x-data="{ app() }">
    <button
        @click="updateContent"
        x-text="title"
    ></button>
</div>
...
<script src="{{ asset('js/my_script.js') }}"></script>
```

my_script.js:

```
function app() {
    return {
        title: 'Hello',
        updateContent: function() {
            title = 'Hello World!';
            // $nextTick(() => { console.log($el.innerText) });
            // $ is not recognize
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this.$nextTick?

Comment: My guess is that you would need to pass it in via the call to `app()` as in `app($nextTick)`. See: [How to Access Alpine.js Magic Properties from inline handlers and function/component methods](https://codewithhugo.com/alpinejs-magic-property-access/)

Comment: Well. I ended up using a setTimeOut function with 1ms of time before calling the console.log function and it worked well. I'm sure that's not the best approach, but I can't find a way to call the nexttick function within the script. I tried "this.$nexttick", doesn't work (this.$nextTick... is not a function this.$nextTick... is undefined). And I'm not sure if passing the function as a parameter will work at all. In the example I put maybe it does, but my script uses a lot of inner call to other methods, classes, async requests to the server, etc.

Comment: For what it's worth.. I needed access to this function within an event handler within a store, and was able to do Alpine.nextTick(() => { Alpine.store('example').updated = true });

Comment: Did you try `this.$nexttick` or `this.$nextTick` (with a capital T for Tick)?